# How I can generate all possible combinations of a 3 and 4 digit number?

Tags: google-sheets

Hi I am trying to generate all possible combinations Of the 3 and 4 digits which are divisible by 12,13 37,101, 111 in columns c and d ....then divide those combinations in their simplest form by dividing by each by 12,13,37,111,101 and place into a single column.. thanks in advance

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BRQO3lNuDXDYXujsDir5wo0xnQ49gzpomxw5zo2qctA/edit?usp=drivesdk

Answer (score 1):

Try these formulas:

```
=filter($C3:$C / E2, $C3:$C / E2 = int($C3:$C / E2), $C3:$C)
=filter($D3:$D / E2, $D3:$D / E2 = int($D3:$D / E2), $D3:$D)
=unique( sort( { E3:E; F3:F; G3:G; H3:H; I3:I; J3:J; K3:K; L3:L; M3:M; N3:N } ) )
```

Note that the results are *not* the 3 Ball and 4 Ball numbers that match the criteria — they are *divided* by the divisors you list, as you requested.

See your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BRQO3lNuDXDYXujsDir5wo0xnQ49gzpomxw5zo2qctA/edit#gid=1738291310).